# File makeDirectory

Tags: laravel-5

I can make a Folder Successfully when a user create his account based on his chosen username but I also want to instruct make sub folders for instance when you create an account with username "john" a folder is created called "john" what about if I want to create sub folders for this user.

So basically when your username is "john" I want to create sub folders like :

> john/folder1
>
> john/folder2
>
> john/folder3

here is the main folder code line :

```
File::MakeDirectory('/home/vagrant/Code/laravel/UserFolders/' . $data['username']);
```

Comment: Where exactly do you wish to create these folders ? Public or resources or storage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by setting recursive option of File::makeDirectory method to true which will create all folders/sub folders in the path if they don't exists:

`File::makeDirectory($path=base_path("public/userfolder/{$data['username']}"), $mode = 0755, $recursive = true, $force = false);`

Comment: it's storage, your syntaxe didnt work for me:
File::makeDirectory($path=base_path("/home/vagrant/Code/laravel/UserFolders/{$data['username']}/folder1"),
            $mode = 0755, $recursive = true, $force = false);

Comment: are you trying to create the folder outside Laravel app? don't specify this: /home/vagrant/Code/laravel/UserFolders/ but use this `File::makeDirectory($path=base_path("UserFolders/{$da‌​ta['username']}/folder1"), $mode = 0755, $recursive = true, $force = false);` that's why I asked where you wish to create the folder

Comment: Welcome @Mark  happy building awesome